# SwaggerJS validation failed: invalid content type (application/json)

Tags: swagger

I'm trying to set up a mock API using [swagger-node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node). I've received the `.yaml` file with all the declarations so it should run out of the box. However when I run it in mock mode it builds, but when I access any route I get an error: `Error: Response validation failed: invalid content type (application/json).  These are valid: */*`

I think the issue is that in each path there is a `consumes` and a `produces`, however I don't really know what they refer to, as I can't find them in the docs (). Below it's a path example as I got it, I've only added the `x-swagger-router-controller` bit. Can anyone help me figure out why this doesn't run straight away?

Example Path

```
'/**/C/{categoryCode}/getSearchPageData':
get:
  tags:
    - category-search-results-rest-controller
  summary: Get Search Page Data
  operationId: getSearchPageDataUsingGET
  consumes:
    - application/json
  produces:
    - '*/*'
  parameters:
    - name: categoryCode
      in: path
      description: category code
      required: true
      type: string
    - name: q
      in: query
      description: search query
      required: false
      type: string
    - name: sort
      in: query
      description: sort
      required: false
      type: string
    - name: pageSize
      in: query
      description: page size
      required: false
      type: integer
      default: 20
      format: int32
    - name: pageNumber
      in: query
      description: page number
      required: false
      type: integer
      format: int32
  responses:
    '200':
      description: OK
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/ProductCategorySearchPageData'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorized
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Not Found
  x-swagger-router-controller: 'getSearchPageData'
```

Comment: Can you post your API definition?

Comment: Was going to copy it and forgot. Will update now.

Comment: And which tool/framework are you using to "set up a mock API"? E.g. [swagger-inflector](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-inflector), [swagger-node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node), [swagger-tools](https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools) or something else?

Comment: I'm using swagger-node

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wildcard (`*/*`) usually corresponds to `application/octet-stream`, which is different from `application/json`. Try changing `produces` to list your actual response media types, e.g.

```
produces:
  - application/json
  - application/xml
```

You should probably also remove `consumes`, because it only applies to requests with a request body, such as POST/PUT/PATCH.

Comment: I tried removing the '*/*' and managed to get something but I didn't think about the `consumes` bit. Makes sense if it is GET to not be there. Thanks for the help!